# Javascript progress bar not working with PHP upload form

Tags: javascript, php, html, progress

I've got JS to run with a php upload form.

Everytime I go to upload a file to test this the file DOES upload but the progress bar doesn't work and I get an 'Upload Aborted' error message.

Below is the JS

```
function _(el) {
            return document.getElementById(el);
        }
        function uploadfile() {
            var file = _("file").files[0];
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file", file);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHander, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "uploader.php");
            ajax.send(formdata);
        }
        function progressHandler(event) {
            var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
            _("progressbar").value = (percent);
        }
        function completeHandler(event) {
            _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Success";
            _("progressbar").value = 0;
        }
        function errorHandler(event) {
            _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
        }
        function abortHander(event) {
            _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
        }
```

This script attachs to an HMTL5 `<progress>` with a default value of 0 and max of 100.

Here is the php file to which I am linking the form to:

```
<?php 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$spc = 'test@email.com';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$link = 'http://www.spcink.com/uploads/' . $email . '%7c' . $name;
if(!empty($file)) {
    mkdir('../uploads/' . $email . '|' . $name, 0777, true);
    move_uploaded_file($file, '../uploads/' . '/'. $email . '|' . $name . '/' . $filename);
    mail($spc, 'File upload from:' . $name, $message . $link);
}
?>
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here.  Could some one please look this over and help me out!  Thank you!